# Как отследить появление и изменение элемента с помощью MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Почитал про MutationObserver, попробовал, но так и не понял как реализовать.

Есть кнопка-гамбургер, которая появляется при размере окна меньше 768px и удаляется, если размер больше.
При клике на гамбургер, добавляем класс *hamburger_active*.

```js
/*
var container = $(".hamburger");

var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);
  });
});

var config = {
 attributes: true,
 characterData: true,
 childList: true,
 subtree: true,
 attributeOldValue: true,
 characterDataOldValue: true
}

observer.observe(container, config);
*/

$(function() {
  $(window).on("load resize", function() {
    var width = $(window).width();

    if (width < 768) {
      if (!$(document).find(".hamburger").length > 0) {
        $("body").append(
          '<button class="hamburger js-hamburger" type="button">' +
          '<span class="hamburger__box">' +
          '<span class="hamburger__inner"></span>' +
          "</span>" +
          "</button>"
        );
      }
    } else {
      $(document)
        .find(".hamburger")
        .remove();
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".js-hamburger", function(e) {
    var $hamburger = $(".hamburger");

    $hamburger.toggleClass("hamburger_active");
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.navbar_active {
  background: #ccc;
}

.hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  right: 16px;
  bottom: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-property: background;
  text-transform: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.hamburger:hover .hamburger__inner::after {
  width: 18px;
}

.hamburger__box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 12px;
}

.hamburger__inner {
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
  transition-duration: 0.075s;
}

.hamburger__inner,
.hamburger__inner::before,
.hamburger__inner::after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.hamburger__inner::before,
.hamburger__inner::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
}

.hamburger__inner::before {
  top: -5px;
  width: 18px;
  transition: top 0.075s 0.12s ease, opacity 0.075s ease;
}

.hamburger__inner::after {
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 13px;
  transition: bottom 0.075s 0.12s ease, width 0.25s, -webkit-transform 0.075s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
  transition: bottom 0.075s 0.12s ease, transform 0.075s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19), width 0.25s;
  transition: bottom 0.075s 0.12s ease, transform 0.075s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19), width 0.25s, -webkit-transform 0.075s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.hamburger_active {
  background: #ccc;
}

.hamburger_active:hover {
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9);
}

.hamburger_active .hamburger__inner,
.hamburger_active .hamburger__inner::before,
.hamburger_active .hamburger__inner::after {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.hamburger_active .hamburger__inner {
  transition-delay: 0.12s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hamburger_active .hamburger__inner::before {
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.075s ease, opacity 0.075s 0.12s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger_active .hamburger__inner::after {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 18px;
  transition: bottom 0.075s ease, -webkit-transform 0.075s 0.12s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  transition: bottom 0.075s ease, transform 0.075s 0.12s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  transition: bottom 0.075s ease, transform 0.075s 0.12s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1), -webkit-transform 0.075s 0.12s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">navbar</div>
```

Как с помощью MutationObserver отследить появления класса *hamburger_active* и, если он присутствует, то блоку с меню добавить *navbar_active*?

Или возможно есть другой способ?

[Пример на Codepen](https://codepen.io/inkshio/pen/BbxbZz).

Comment: При добавлении гамбургера, вешаете на него обработчик клика, в котором и проверяете наличие классов у нужных элементов. Как я понимаю, весь код ваш, и Вы его полностью контролируете. MutationObserver, в данном случае - лишнее. Чаще всего, его используют, при добавлении своего кода на страницу, управляемую сторонними скриптами и изменить поведение которых, нет возможности, но можно отслеживать результаты действий.

Answer (score 0):

Можно проще, без MutationObserver:

```
document.querySelector('.hamburger').onclick = function() {
  this.classList.contains('hamburger_active') ?
  document.querySelector('.navbar')?.classList.add('navbar_active') :
  document.querySelector('.navbar')?.classList.remove('navbar_active')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Есть способ попроще - событие изменения атрибутов элемента. Оно использовалось до появления MutationObserver, но до сих пор поддерживается браузерами:

`Element.onDOMAttrModified = function() {}`

Для появления элемента - событие `DOMNodeInserted`.

Comment: на developer.mozilla пишут что этот функционал устарел и рекомендуют именно `MutationObserver`

Comment: В курсе, но пробовал в Chrome и отлично работает. Синтаксис самый простой. Просто `MutationObserver` имеет расширенные настройки, поэтому его и рекомендуют. Но если нужно просто отследить изменение или появление элемента, то `DOMAttrModified`/`DOMNodeInserted` отличный и, главное, самый короткий способ. Когда создают более расширенные новые методы, то старые так и продолжают хорошо работать, как и раньше. И всегда рекомендуют использовать новое, но очень часто старое намного удобнее и проще в плане синтаксиса.